# How to trigger the template plugin from outside tinyMCE 4 editor

Tags: php, tinymce, tinymce-4

I have a project that uses the 'template' plugin on tinyMCE 4. I need to invoke the 'Insert Template' on an outside button (or create a function that does the similar) The button can be added within the toolbar by adding 'toolbar:template'.

```js
tinyMCE.init({
    selector: '#my_editor',
    plugins: ["template"],
    toolbar1: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent template"
   });
```

```html
<textarea id="my_editor"></textarea>
<button>INVOKE INSERT TEMPLATE HERE</button>
```

**[Here is my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/elymentree/o1wkpacy/17/)**

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the built-in template, I have created my own function that fetches pre defined HTML pages and loads them to tinyMCE through execCommand (I am using [VEX Dialogue](http://github.hubspot.com/vex/) to load my UI):

```
 $('button#template').click(function(){
   $.ajax({
            statusCode : { 404: function(){alert('Not Found');} },
            type       : 'post',
            data       : {},
            url        : '<script_that_load_my_templates>',
            success    : function(res){ 

                         vex.dialog.open({
                             message:'Select a layout',
                             input: res,
                             callback:function(data){
                                 if(data.layout !== undefined){

                                   tinyMCE.activeEditor.execCommand('mceInsertContent',false,data.content);
                                 }
                             } // CALLBACK BLOCK
                         });
                         //}); // END FANCYBOX

                     } // END SUCCESS BLOCK
    }); // end ajax */   
}); // END BUTTON LAYOUT CLICK EVENT
```

Answer (score 0):

Here ya go:

`$('.mce-i-template').trigger('click')`

Comment: Please make this a full answer, not just a code answer with no explanation.

Comment: Code only answers can generally be improved by adding some explanatory text to them.